# Trying to extract only sentences which include specific words in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I just started learning Javascript, and I'm trying to code a way to extract and write in a list only sentences that include specific words in a text.

This is the idea I had here below, but this is obviously not working and I do not find any solution. Could you please give me some syntax advice or anything?

```js
function DetectConcl() {
  var Conclusions = ["so", "hence", "as a consequence"];
  var Entry = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  var EntryLow = Entry.toLowerCase();
  var Sentences = EntryLow.split(".");
  var Results = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < Conclusions.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Sentences.length; j++) {
      if (Sentences[j].includes(Conclusions[i])) {
        Results.push(Sentences[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  for (var k = 0; k < Results.length; k++) {
    document.getElementById("conclusion").children[0].innerHTML += "<li>" + Results[k] + "</li>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="enter" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Enter text" onclick="DetectConcl()">
<div id="conclusion">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like its working to me? Can you share your test data and anticipated result?

Comment: If you know regexes, then it is the easiest way to solve your problem. Simply create an array of regexes that match "so", "hence" and "as a consequence" and run a test on each sentence `conclusionsRegexes[i].test(sentences[j])`. This way you can build more complex matching system.

Comment: Can you say exactly what is not working? After testing it with the sentence `"so hence this is working"` I got an output of 2 sentences

Comment: I entered _"This is so can test. No words here. Then hence it is true."_ — 2 of the 3 sentences match, and that is exactly the output I got.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Strange, for me, it did not seem to work, but I was testing this code with jsfiddle. Maybe that was the reason. Thanks for the regexes method, I did not know this one!